# Adding class/jar file to IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Is there any way to add .class/.jar file to InelliJ IDEA, so that It will be added to every project created.

I tried

- Adding .class to JDK lib/ext directory
- Adding it to IntelliJ lib directory

Comment: Tip: You might want to consider investing some time into learning to use [Maven](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven). IntelliJ fully supports using Maven to automatically download and install various software libraries you want to use in your projects. This kind of tool is formally known as a “dependency manager”.

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/libraries-and-global-libraries.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a new library in File -> Project Structure -> Global Libraries. Then add your classes/jars to that library.

This library will NOT be automatically added to every project you create. Because, this may not be desired in many cases.

You have to add the library to projects manually. You can do it in: File -> Project Structure -> Modules -> Dependencies

Answer (score 2):

Add your jar here: File | Project Structure | Global Libraries