# how to add a jar file into intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I have a jar file which is a bunch of .class files(Java). I need to use some of the classes inside of the jar file into my intellij project. I followed these instructions:

[Adding class/jar file to IntelliJ IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54495522/adding-class-jar-file-to-intellij-idea)

The jar file did successfully link into the project as an external library. But, I am not able to access any of it's classes. Nor am I able to import any files from it. Can some one help me out ?

Comment: Maybe you forgot to add the import statement to the top of your class? Could you please add your class to the question?

Comment: Did you add the library to the [module dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#working-with-module-dependencies) as well?